# Is it possible to use brotli compression in React?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, brotli

My webpack bundle is quite heavy (2.3mb). I recently read articles about brotli compression, but all of them talk about a classic set up with js files served by a server. So the compression happens in the backend. My question may be stupid, but is it possible to apply such a compression to my webpack chunks in a React app (I already use Terser plugin default configuration)?

Comment: How is your web application served if not via a web server?

Comment: On a third party such as Netlify. But I don't have my own node server on this one. Also, assuming I had my own Node server, how would I be able to compress the webpack bundle/chunks? It's just a frontend app for the moment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Netlify (or whoever they are using to actually serve the files) already does file compression, so you don't have to worry about it. Compression is usually not done at the build step because the client getting the files might not be able to decompress them. Usually the client tells the server what it is capable of (e.g. "Give me this file and I'm able to understand gzip compression") and the server response accordingly. If the client doesn't say it understands gzip compression, the server won't compress the file.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of compression should be handled by the server in realtime in my opinion but you can build `brotli` compression of your files via `webpack` plugins as well please check out:

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/compression-webpack-plugin/#using-brotli

please note that only build files will have `brotli` compression here not API calls and other assets.

Comment: Should I use it if I already have Terser Plugin activated? Also, will all browsers be able to read the bundle (IE for example)?

Comment: Terser plugin only helps with minifying your js but `brotli` is a compression method which will reduce the transferring size of your file from server to client such as when you `zip` or `rar` your files to make them smaller to get less space or deliver them faster. also, all browser can't read them they send accept method from the header and the server will serve appropriate file that they can work with you will have both js and `brotli` files on your server